# Use wildcards in makedev devite table

Tags: permissions, buildroot

I'm reading the [documentation](http://underpop.online.fr/b/buildroot/en/makedev-syntax.htm.gz) about makedev syntax in order to set the permissions of some files in my Buildroot environment. For example I need to set the Network Manager connection files to 600, etc...

It `type` is `r` the permissions are applied *for the directory and all files and directories below it*. Instead I want they are applied for the files under the directory *only*.

Am I allowed to do something like this?

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* f  600 0 0 - - - - -
```

I mean, I tried and it does not accept this syntax:

```
makedevs: line 26: regular file '/home/mark/dev/buildroot/output/build/buildroot-fs/ext2/target/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*' does not exist: No such file or directory
```

but perhaps there is another syntax to use. It's error prone to list here all the files.